# Particular Query in Linq It does not perform the same thing as an inner join in SQL Server

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012

This query is being carried out to take the zone and category names from the respective Product-related tables.

```
SELECT
    Categoria.NombreCategoria,
    Zona.ZonaGrupo,
    p.NombreProducto,
    p.ProductoTiene,
    p.RealizadosEvento,
    p.FechaInicial,
    p.FechaFin 
FROM
    Productos p
INNER JOIN
    Categoria ON p.CategoriaId = Categoria.Id 
INNER JOIN
    Zona ON p.ZonaId = Zona.ZonaId
```

The result of the SQL query returns the 1000 records that the products table must have with their zones and categories.

When doing the following in linq, it returns only 8 records ...

```
IQueryable<ProductosViewModel> ProductosMaped = 
      from p in Db.Productos
      join g in Db.Zona on p.ZonaId equals g.ZonaId
      join acr in Db.Categoria on p.CategoriaId equals acr.Id
      select new ProductosViewModel
                 {
                     Categoria        = acr.NombreCategoria,
                     ZonaGrupo        = g.ZonaGrupo,
                     NombreProducto   = p.NombreProducto,
                     ProductoTiene    = p.ProductoTiene,
                     RealizadosEvento = p.RealizadosEvento,
                     FechaInicial     = p.FechaInicial,
                     FechaFin         = p.FechaFin,
                 };
```

I only need to link these 2 tables so that list only shows me CategoryName and ZoneName or Group Zone.

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so, you don't need to use `join` in Linq, just use Navigation Properties.

Comment: Please post the SQL that EF generated. You can see it by using `IQueryable<T>.ToString()` or `Db.Database.Log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better idea: Use `Include` with navigation properties:

```
List<ProductosViewModel> list = await this.Db.Productos
    .Include( p => p.Zona )
    .Include( p => p.Categoria )
    .Where( p => p.Categoria != null && p.Zona != null ) // <-- This step may be optional depending on your database.
    .Select( p => new ProductosViewModel
    {
        Categoria        = p.Categoria.NombreCategoria,
        ZonaGrupo        = p.Zona.ZonaGrupo,
        NombreProducto   = p.NombreProducto,
        ProductoTiene    = p.ProductoTiene,
        RealizadosEvento = p.RealizadosEvento,
        FechaInicial     = p.FechaInicial,
        FechaFin         = p.FechaFin,
    } )
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```